# finding cofactor and determinant of a 3x3 matrix (java)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I computed the product, sum, and transpose(of product), but I have no clue where to start on the cofactor and determinent of the product matrix.

Ive seen a couple examples but none that resemble my particular code so if anyone could show me how i could incorporate these two methods into my program  I'd high appreciate it.

please dont ask me what i've tried because as I stated I am clueless at the moment

```
//here is the code I wrote for the product:

package programEx;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class progEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Establishing Input Stream
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter number of rows in A: ");
       int rowsInA = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter number of columns in A / rows in B: ");
       int columnsInA = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter number of columns in B: ");
       int columnsInB = s.nextInt();

       int[][] a = new int[rowsInA][columnsInA];
       int[][] b = new int[columnsInA][columnsInB];

 //Taking user input for 1st matrix
       System.out.println("Enter matrix A");
       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
               a[i][j] = s.nextInt();
           }
       }
 //Taking user input for 2nd matrix
       System.out.println("Enter matrix B");
       for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
               b[i][j] = s.nextInt();
           }
       }

 //calling the multiplication method and passing it to both matrices
       int[][] c = multiply(a, b);
       System.out.println("Product of A and B is");
       for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < c[0].length; j++) {
               System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");

           } 
           System.out.println();
       } 

  }

//Separate method for the multiplication of 1st and 2nd matrices
   public static int[][] multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
       int rowsInA = a.length;
       int columnsInA = a[0].length; 
       int columnsInB = b[0].length;
       int[][] c = new int[rowsInA][columnsInB];
       for (int i = 0; i < rowsInA; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < columnsInB; j++) {
               for (int k = 0; k < columnsInA; k++) {
                   c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
               }
           }
       }
       return c;
   }
}
```

Comment: Clueless isn't a good start.  Determinant and cofactor of a matrix ought to be known to you.  If you can calculate those for a matrix, then you can do it for the product of two matricies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,a 3*3 matrix has 3 columns and 3 rows to begin with.
Each starts with an index 0.

Determinant can be calculated as:

```
int d=determinant();
int determinant()
{
  int x=a[0][0]*((a[1][1]*a[2][2])-(a[2][1]*a[1][2]));
   int y=-a[0][1]*((a[0][1]*a[2][2])-(a[2][0]*a[1][2]));
 int z=a[0][2]*((a[1][0]*a[2][1])-(a[1][1]*a[2][0]));

    int r=x+y+z;
    return r;
    }
```

This is only for finding the determinant of a 3*3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

public int getDeterminante() {

```
    int x = ((matriz[0][0] * matriz[1][1] * matriz[2][2]) + (matriz[0][1] * matriz[1][2] * matriz[2][0]) + (matriz[0][2] * matriz[1][0] * matriz[2][1]));
    int y = ((matriz[0][2] * matriz[1][1] * matriz[2][0]) + (matriz[0][0] * matriz[1][2] * matriz[2][1]) + (matriz[0][1] * matriz[1][0] * matriz[2][2]));
    

    int r = x - y ;
    return r;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).